# while downloading react pacakge i am not getting src gitnore and some other files

Tags: reactjs

waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~/robofriends$ npm start
npm ERR! missing script: start

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/waseem/.npm/_logs/2020-01-31T15_14_28_462Z-debug.log

Comment: you don't have `start` script inside `package.json`

Comment: yes some files are not in my package.json files

Comment: i tried this commands here 
sudo  npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: this is not a file, this should be a script, which run some commands, like: `"scripts": {"start": "node scripts/start.js"}`

Comment: Check [Create react app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) docs

Comment: it was showing that now its a outdated to install react app like this npm create-react-app  now i am uninstalling that package globally and then i will try this "npx create-react-app my-app" and i will let you know this later

Comment: A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

Comment: what's your npm version?

Comment: just try `npm init react-app my-app`

Comment: "npx create-react-app my_sample_app" i tried even this but again getting the same problem .. now its showing this error " npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/waseem/.npm/_logs/2020-01-31T16_24_59_117Z-debug.log"

Comment: my npm version is 6.13.6

Comment: please post result of `where create-react-app` command

Comment: + react@16.12.0
+ react-scripts@3.3.1
+ react-dom@16.12.0
added 1549 packages from 747 contributors and audited 918300 packages in 262.729s

46 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities


A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.

Comment: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

Comment: Seems like you have installed create-react-app globally. If you can't remove it via npm, you need to remove it manually.

Comment: yes i tried this before but getting same problem

Comment: waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~$ npm uninstall -g create-react-app
removed 91 packages in 1.478s

Comment: run now this `npm list -g create-react-app`

Comment: waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~$ npm list -g create-react-app
/home/waseem/.nvm/versions/node/v12.5.0/lib
`-- (empty)

Comment: now you can create it without global install: `npm install create-react-app` then `npm init react-app my_app`

Comment: waseem@waseem-HP-Laptop-14q-cs0xxx:~$ npm install create-react-app
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/waseem/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/waseem/package.json'
npm WARN waseem No description
npm WARN waseem No repository field.
npm WARN waseem No README data
npm WARN waseem No license field.

+ create-react-app@3.3.1
added 92 packages from 46 contributors and audited 296 packages in 25.754s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: hm, seems like they changed something. Try to create a folder with your app and inside this folder run first `npm init`, press enter few times and then try again `npm install create-react-app`

Comment: thank you so much now its working